# Building Query Expressions with Generic Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need help finishing this query. I need to use Expressions so that i can handle the query dynamicly. In other words, the user builds the query parameters that get pushed into this. I need help specifically with the Generic types referenced in the lines `Type yourType = typeof(YourGeneric);` , & `ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(yourType, "x");` & `Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, yourType.GetProperty(wheres[i].ColumnName))`.. Full disclosure, I am doing this off of another recomendation and do not fully understand generics. Please refer to [Entity Framework Dynamic Where Clause from List<object>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50136696/entity-framework-dynamic-where-clause-from-listobject) for more details.

```
Expression query;
for (int i = 0; i < wheres.Count; i++)
{
    Type yourType = typeof(YourGeneric);
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(yourType, "x");
    Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, yourType.GetProperty(wheres[i].ColumnName));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(wheres[i].Value, typeof(int));

    Expression result = getOperatorExp(wheres[i].Operator, left, right);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        query = result;
    }
    else
    {
        Expression grammer = getGrammerExp(wheres[i].AndOr, query, result);
        query = grammer;
    }


}

MasterQuery.Where(query);


public Expression getOperatorExp(string Operator, Expression left, Expression right)
{
    Expression exp;
    switch (Operator.ToUpper())
    {
        case "Equals":
            exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);
            break;

        case "NOT EQUALS":
            exp = Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
            break;

        case "LESS THAN":
            exp = Expression.LessThan(left, right);
            break;

        case "LESS THAN OR EQUALS":
            exp = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;

        case "GREATER THAN":
            exp = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
            break;

        case "GREATER THAN OR EQUALS":
            exp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;

        case "ON":
            exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);
            break;

        case "BEFORE":
            exp = Expression.LessThan(left, right);
            break;

        case "ON OR BEFORE":
            exp = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;

        case "AFTER":
            exp = Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
            break;

        case "ON OR AFTER":
            exp = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
            break;

        default:
            exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);
            break;
    }

    return exp;
}

        public Expression getGrammerExp(string AndOr, Expression left, Expression right)
        {
            Expression exp;
            switch (AndOr.ToUpper())
            {
                case "AND":
                    exp = Expression.And(left, right);
                    break;

                case "OR":
                    exp = Expression.Or(left, right);
                    break;

                case "":
                    exp = Expression.LessThan(left, right);
                    break;

                default:
                    exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);
                    break;
            }

            return exp;
        }
```

Comment: You are taking `YourGeneric` literally. you just need the type in the collection you intend to call the expression against. For example in a collection `context.Set<Book>()`, your type would be `typeof(Book)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what my implementation would look like.

Test code:

```
var masterQuery = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Asterix", Weight = 50 },
    new { Name = "Obelix", Weight = 120 },
    new { Name = "Idefix", Weight = 1 }
}.AsQueryable();

var wheres = new[]
{
    new Filtering.WhereParams { ColumnName = "Name", Operator = "Equals", Value = "Asterix" },
    new Filtering.WhereParams { AndOr = "OR", ColumnName = "Name", Operator = "Equals", Value = "Obelix" },
    new Filtering.WhereParams { AndOr = "AND", ColumnName = "Weight", Operator = "LESS THAN", Value = 100 }
};

var filtered = masterQuery.Where(wheres).ToList();
// asterix
```

And here's the implementation:

```
public static class Filtering
{
    public class WhereParams
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }
        public object Value { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string AndOr { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Make a predicate from the specified <paramref name="wheres"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ToPredciate<T>(this IEnumerable<WhereParams> wheres)
    {
        using (var e = wheres.GetEnumerator())
        {
            if (!e.MoveNext()) // not filtered
                return x => true;

            var pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
            var body = GetComparePredicateBody(pe, e.Current); // first condition

            // join body with more conditions
            while (e.MoveNext())
            {
                var right = GetComparePredicateBody(pe, e.Current);
                switch (e.Current.AndOr)
                {
                    case "AND":
                        body = Expression.AndAlso(body, right);
                        break;
                    case "OR":
                        body = Expression.OrElse(body, right);
                        break;
                    default:
                        // LessThan and Equal don't make much sense on booleans, do they?
                        throw new Exception("Bad boolean operator.");
                }
            }

            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, pe);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a boolean expression x.ColumnName op Value.
    /// </summary>
    private static Expression GetComparePredicateBody(Expression x, WhereParams where)
    {
        var left = Expression.Property(x, where.ColumnName);
        var right = Expression.Constant(where.Value);
        switch (where.Operator)
        {
            case "Equals": return Expression.Equal(left, right);
            case "LESS THAN": return Expression.LessThan(left, right);
            // ...
            default: throw new ArgumentException("Bad comparison operator.");
        }
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<WhereParams> wheres) => source.Where(wheres.ToPredciate<T>());
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<WhereParams> wheres) => source.Where(wheres.ToPredciate<T>().Compile());
}
```

Comment: This is great! Please explain `public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<WhereParams> wheres) => source.Where(wheres.ToPredciate<T>());`& `public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, IEnumerable<WhereParams> wheres) => source.Where(wheres.ToPredciate<T>().Compile());` I am getting errors on these lines.

Comment: Compilation errors? Maybe because it's an expression-bodied method, introduced in C#6.0. `int TheAnswer() => 42` is equivalent to `int TheAnswer() { return 42; }`.

Answer (score 1):

YourGeneric should be the entity type, which you want to query. For instance, if in your DbContext you have a collection of Cities (DbSet Cities) you should pass that type as your generic type.

You don't want to write custom code for each entity type in your context. The code you are writing should work for both querying Cities table and for querying Fruits table. Hence - the use of generics.

As an example:

```
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(City), "x");
```

Will create an expression for a lambda parameter of type City, which can be used to query collection of that type. To make the code reusable you can make it generic (as stated in your question) and something along these lines:

```
public Expression CreateExpression<TEntity, TConst>(WhereClause singleWhere)
{ 
    Type entityType = typeof(TEntity);
    ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "x");
    Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, 
        entityType.GetProperty(singleWhere.ColumnName));
    Expression right = Expression.Constant(singleWhere.Value, typeof(TConst));

    return getOperatorExp(singleWhere.Operator, left, right);
}
```

You can then pass appropriate types in your calls like this:

```
Expression result = CreateExpression<City, int>();
```

This allows you to pass a different type of entity and a different type of constant to query against with each call.

Also, this should probably be upper case:

```
case "Equals":
```

It would be good if your code sample was compilable to a degree - it would make it easier for me to give you a working sample. Expression trees in .NET is a much more complex topic, than generics.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Does this example also require adding the "AND" and "OR" components?

Comment: Yes, what I've written is just an example, of how you can use generics to your advantage. AndOr allows you to chain the aggregated where conditions into single where statement with multiple conditions.